# What is the core difference between material ui popover and popper ? Any diff use cases?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, popover, popper

Material UI is documentation is unarguably most close to perfect open source project docs for react developers but there are some unclear things like exact difference between [Popover](https://v4.mui.com/components/popover/#popover) and [Popper](https://v4.mui.com/components/popper/#popper). Can someone explain me in short what is the core difference between this two ??

Comment: doesn't it explain in the docs section you linked?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As it's explained in the doc :

**Popover**

> Things to know when using the Popover component:
>
> The component is built on top of the Modal component. The scroll and
> click away are blocked unlike with the Popper component.

**Popper**

> Clicking away does not hide the Popper component. If you need this
> behavior, you can use ClickAwayListener - see the example in the menu
> documentation section.

Answer (score 9):

A PopOver behaves more like a modal, blocking user action/scroll until it is dismissed with a click outside of itself.

Popper is just a thing that pops, doesn't impose anything upon the user, and doesn't disappear by default if you click away, so it's less intrusive to the user experience.

Comment: Then what is the difference between Popover and modal